# Clear terminal window before tail -f output

Tags: bash, tail

I have the following script running every 3 minutes with cron:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Documents/Fetch/
wget remotehost/data.txt --output-document=tmp
cp tmp data.txt
rm tmp
```

To fetch a self-generated php log.

I want to check if any changes have been made to the file (with a 3 minute timespan). So in a terminal on my second screen, i'm running `tail -f ~/Documents/Fetch/`

Now, if no changes are made to the data.txt file, tail just outputs the same log over and over again, separated by `tail: /home/midas/Documents/Fetch/data.txt: file truncated`.

is there a way to tell `tail` to completely `clear` the terminal screen before showing the output when the file is truncated?

I basically want this to happen:

1. tail prints initial content
2. tail notices the file is truncated > `clear`
3. tail prints the content it sees after truncation of the file.

The `man tail` page did not seem to give me this option.

Does anyone have experience with this?

I know it kinda beats the purpose of tail itself, but I can imagine a few situations where this would be handy.

Comment: Like with `clear && tail -f $filename`?

Comment: No, I actually want clear to be ran everytime `tail -f` prints new content. (As I'm completely copying the new logfile over the old one).
`clear && tail -f $filename` clears everything, and then it starts running `tail -f`

Comment: Sorry I'm too tired and I'll go to sleep. `watch tail $filename` may also help. I am too sleepy to understand the question. Will check it tomorrow. :)

Comment: I don't think watch and tail go well together. It doesn't quite do what I hope it would anyways.

I might be a bit unclear, I'll see if I can clarify further :) Thanks for the effort!

Comment: Chances are that you are indeed clear, but I'm just too tired. Will check tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your content is relatively short (less than one terminal screen's worth, for whatever number of lines in your terminal), then you can run the `tail` repeatedly

```
watch -n 30 'tail /path/to/filename 2>&1'
```

This runs the `tail` every 30 seconds. You might want to use a different interval (the default is 2 seconds, but since you have a generation granularity of 3 minutes there's no a lot of point in having it that low).

For subtle changes the `-d` flag can also be useful to highlight differences.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't too familiar with `watch` but with these params it indeed does what I hoped it would!

Comment: @Midas, actually thinking about it a little more, `cat /path/to/filename` instead of `tail /path/to/filename` should be equally effective

Comment: @ roaima You're right, it's actually even better as it'll show the whole content and with the `-d` flag on `watch` it'll highlight the changes.

Thx for the tip!